# How to get SQLite connection id?

Tags: sqlite

In MySQL I can get the connection id by executing `SELECT CONNECTION_ID()`. 
How to do something similar in SQLite? I can't find anything about that in the docs at https://www.sqlite.org.

Comment: SQLite doesn't have connections like MySQL has, since it's just programs accessing the data file directly, without a database server in between. What do you need it for?

Comment: I don't know that SQLite has connection IDs. It's meant to be used with only one application accessing it at a time, so it wouldn't make a lot of sense to have.

Comment: @mypetlion "SQLite works great as the database engine for most low to medium traffic websites (which is to say, most websites)." - https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html. So, it is not only for one app at a time.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica For query logging in order to make it easier to find queries executed by a single HTTP request for example.

Comment: That seems like the wrong approach for a SQLite database.